# Having trouble with declared functions in `~/.profile` not being loaded in integrated terminal shells

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I have a `.profile` which is copied to /home/vscode during my container build before running `common-debian.sh`

*This is important as during container image build `common-delian.sh` will skip creating a default .profile if the file is already present*

In that profile I have a number of bash functions and some exported variables.

One of the variables relies on executing one of the declared functions, and in my shell I can see the correct variable and value is set.

*This problem arises when opening a new integrated terminal in vscode.
"new terminal" command*

However none of my functions are available in the shell to execute.
Confirmed through `typeset -F`

I can run `source ~/.profile` and the functions are then available in the shell.

Is there some place I can turn up logging to determine what is happening here?

Details about the install

vscode Host install is Mac M1

```
VERSION='0.202.6'
CONTENTS_URL='https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/debian/history/0.202.6.md'
DEFINITION_ID='debian'
VARIANT='bullseye'
GIT_REPOSITORY='https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/'
GIT_REPOSITORY_RELEASE='v0.224.0'
BUILD_TIMESTAMP='Fri, 25 Feb 2022 10:48:36 GMT'
```

Example function declaration

```
kconfig() {
 ls $HOME/.kube/configs/* | tr '\n' ':'
}
declare -f kconfig
```

Example variable making use

```
export KUBECONFIG="$(kconfig)"
```

I can confirm before sourcing .profile, this variable is set and valid and should only have come from the .profile declaration.

home folder for reference

```
vscode ➜ /workspace (master ✗) $ ls -al ~
total 76
drwxr-xr-x  1 vscode vscode  4096 Apr 27 18:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4096 Feb 25 10:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1    501 dialout  160 Mar  8 22:31 .aws
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode   220 Aug  4  2021 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode  4665 Feb 25 10:55 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  3 vscode vscode  4096 Apr 27 18:59 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  1    501 dialout  192 Apr 25 21:41 .config
drwxr-xr-x  1    501 dialout  160 Apr 27 14:20 .creds
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode   500 Apr 27 18:59 .gitconfig
drwx------  2 vscode vscode  4096 Apr 27 18:59 .gnupg
drwxr-xr-x  1    501 dialout  160 Mar  9 21:59 .kube
drwxr-xr-x 12 vscode vscode  4096 Feb 25 10:55 .oh-my-zsh
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode  2381 Apr 27 19:19 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  1 vscode root    4096 Apr 27 18:59 .vscode-server
drwxr-xr-x  3 vscode root    4096 Apr 27 18:26 .vscode-server-insiders
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode  3897 Feb 25 10:55 .zshrc
```

*Edit below:*

---

Now I am copying this file in as `~/.bash_profile`
There is still a .profile, vscode `common-debian.sh` creates this if the file is not present when building the container image.

```
vscode ➜ /workspace (master ✗) $ ls -al ~
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  1 vscode vscode  4096 Apr 27 20:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    4096 Feb 25 10:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x  1    501 dialout  160 Mar  8 22:31 .aws
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode   220 Aug  4  2021 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode  2671 Apr 27 19:57 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode  4665 Feb 25 10:55 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  3 vscode vscode  4096 Apr 27 20:08 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  1    501 dialout  192 Apr 25 21:41 .config
drwxr-xr-x  1    501 dialout  160 Apr 27 14:20 .creds
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode   500 Apr 27 20:08 .gitconfig
drwx------  2 vscode vscode  4096 Apr 27 20:08 .gnupg
drwxr-xr-x  1    501 dialout  160 Mar  9 21:59 .kube
drwxr-xr-x 12 vscode vscode  4096 Feb 25 10:55 .oh-my-zsh
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode   807 Aug  4  2021 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  1 vscode root    4096 Apr 27 20:08 .vscode-server
drwxr-xr-x  3 vscode root    4096 Apr 27 20:07 .vscode-server-insiders
-rw-r--r--  1 vscode vscode  3897 Feb 25 10:55 .zshrc
```

also added the following to /etc/profile.d/

```
# This file is intended to be copied into /etc/profile.d
project_profile="$HOME/.bash_profile"
if [ -r $project_profile ]; then
  source $project_profile
else
  echo "File not found or not readable: $project_profile"
fi
```

none of which has had an effect on the resulting new shells
perhaps ignoring vscode
`docker exec -it {container} /bin/bash` still has the same results.

I have also tried creating an empty terminal profile with an empty shell profile, launching vscode from that terminal window.
Thinking that perhaps inherited env was causing issues.

Also set the following user setting
`"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,`

Comment: A few suggestions: nothing specific to `bash` should be placed  in `.profile`, as it could be used by shells other than `bash`. If you already have a `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` file, `bash` will ignore `.profile` in favor of the more `bash`-specific versions. Finally, if you are running a script, it uses a non-interactive shell that won't source any of the standard files, which are intended for interactive and login shells.

Comment: I am aware of the various file precedence, I have tried to ensure that only .profile is used.

bash specific is okay here, renaming to .bash_profile makes no difference in the outcome.

I am using the default "new terminal" in vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page for bash (in the INVOCATION section):

> When bash is started non-interactively, to  run  a  shell  script,  for
> example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands
> its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the  name
> of  a  file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following command
> were executed:
>
> `if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi`
>
> but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the  filename.

In your use case, i.e. a shell script, no startup file is read. But you can change that by setting the value of BASH_ENV to a file you want to read on startup. Alternately your script can source anything you like when it runs, e.g. `source .profile`.

**Extracted from answer comments:**

Original Poster noted that the issue was fixed using this in vscode:

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
  "bash": {
    "path": "/bin/bash",
    "icon": "terminal-bash",
    "args": [ "-l" ]
  },
}
```

(The `-l` arg to make it a login shell being, probably, the important part?)

Comment: Just a clarifying question, in vscode opening a new terminal is considered "non-interactive"?

I believe I understand how I created this confusion, editing incoming

Comment: @jbreiding In my reading, that depends on your OS... per [this FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_why-are-there-duplicate-paths-in-the-terminals-path-environment-variable-andor-why-are-they-reversed), in macOS all shells are login shells, but on Linux they aren't. You talk about a Mac M1, but you also talk about containers, so I'm not sure which applies in this case.

Comment: the shell is launching from a Debian bullseye based container.

So this line I need to add to my .profile?

Comment: What a container runs at startup would depend on the image. In my experience most run a non-login shell. You can check the image's startup command with something like this. Sub your image name: `docker image inspect --format '{{.Config.Entrypoint}} {{.Config.Cmd}}' alpine:latest`

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe that is what is happening when vscode opens a new terminal.
Entrypoint and CMD are completely different.

vscode is opening a new shell from the "new terminal" command. This I would have considered interactive and flow through this path.

I have just tried adding a simple loader in /etc/profile.d, that should cover non-interactive?

Comment: This is probably closer to running
`docker exec -it {container} /bin/bash`

That should be interactive?

Comment: Result of image inspect is
`[] [bash]`

result of container inspect is
`[/bin/sh -c echo Container started
 trap "exit 0" 15
 
 exec "$@"
 while sleep 1 & wait $!; do :; done - /usr/local/share/docker-init.sh] [sleep infinity]`

without diving into the vscode internals, I assume a new terminal is like another process spawning in a container

Comment: I gave a shot at this, "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false. Unfortunately my situation hasn't changed.

Also created an empty terminal profile and launched vscode from there, no luck either.

Comment: This "fixed" it

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
      "bash": {
        "path": "/bin/bash",
        "icon": "terminal-bash",
        "args": [
          "-l"
        ]
      },
    }
```

Comment: Seems like according to that FAQ I shouldn't have to set this for these terminal sessions to be login interactive.

Comment: So I have the same issue. And it seems that the first shell panel is not my "defaultProfile". I can only get this to work when I open new Terminal panels.

Comment: maybe related? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123188